# Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::with does not exist

Tags: laravel, eloquent, collections, model, controller

[image: Controller]

[image: Model]

[image: Error]

What could be the solution?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: the model should be like this]

[Here is the reference](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)

Please refer to the given link. the parameter should be similar like the example of the given link.

Comment: Is this supposed to be an answer or part of your question? In the first case, please read [answer] and then clarify. In the latter, please delete this and edit your question instead.

Answer (score 0):

this line:

```
$fileValue= T_S_Ticket::where("tstID","=",$id)->get();
```

return a collection, so when you use 'with' the next line you got this error.
to fix it, simply load the relation and take the only result in the same line:

```
$fileValue= T_S_Ticket::with('fields')->find($id);
```

Comment: `        $fileValue = T_S_Ticket::with('files')->where("tstID", "=", $id)->get();
` I tried this but now there is an error for column not found..  `Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'messages.file_id' in 'field list' (SQL: select `files`.*, `messages`.`file_id` as `laravel_through_key` from `files` inner join `messages` on `messages`.`id` = `files`.`msgID` where `messages`.`file_id` in (0))`